# php ldap connection function issue

Tags: php, php-7, phpldapadmin

I use ubuntu server and installed default LAMP package
I run ldap query with php however I get following error message ;

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()
>   in

I insert extension=php_ldap.so and extension=ldap.so paramater in php.ini file
however, I want to install php ldap package i get following error message;

> php7.0-ldap : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.4-7ubuntu1) but
>   7.0.4-7ubuntu2 is to be installed

so, I can't install this package

How can I enable ldap package for php7.0?

How can I enable ldap extension for php7.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue, download files php7.0-ldap_7.0.4-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb from https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/ and install manuel via dpkg